# Simple frame animation in Cocos2d V3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am struggling to get a simple animation working in Cocos2d V3.

I initially had a simple static png used for a sprite, using this code, which works fine...

```
Sprite *treeStar = Sprite::create("star.png");
this->addChild(treeStar,+3);
treeStar->setPosition.... // set position is defined later
```

I have added the following code to try a simple animation instead of the static sprite...

```
auto cache = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
Vector<SpriteFrame*> frames = Vector<SpriteFrame*>();
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("star1.png"));
frames.pushBack(cache->getSpriteFrameByName("star2.png"));
cocos2d::Animation* anim = cocos2d::Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(frames, 0.1f, 1);
cocos2d::Animate* anim_action = cocos2d::Animate::create(anim);
Sprite *treeStar = Sprite::create("star1.png");
this->addChild(treeStar,+3);
treeStar->runAction(RepeatForever::create(anim_action));
treeStar->setPosition.... // set position is defined later
```

But this doesn't work and causes my app to crash.

Can anyone help advise how to get this code working, or give me another code example that will work for a simple animation?

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
Sprite *treeStar = Sprite::create("star1.png"); // crash due to image not found
```

The method `create` is used to create a sprite from an individual image not from sprite sheet. In your case, images are in a sprite sheet, change the line to:

```
Sprite *treeStar = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("star1.png");
```